# How to find a height of attributedString that contains multiple fonts in iOS?

Tags: ios, text, core-text

Assume you have an `NSAttributedString` that contains some random number of different fonts. For normal text, you can use

```
boundingRect(
    with size: CGSize, 
    options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], 
    attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]? = nil, 
    context: NSStringDrawingContext?
)
```

to calculate its height.

But how can someone calculate an `NSAttributedString` containing multiple fonts? For example, location 0 to 5 has `UIFont.systemFont(with: 15)` and 6 to 10 has `UIFont.systemFont(with: 17)` and 11 to 16 has `UIFont.systemFont(with: 5)`.

Since `boundingRect` method does not recognize which attributes apply to at what range, it cannot be used. What else can I do to achieve this?

Comment: NSAttributedString has `boundingRect` function itself. Did you try it? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrect?changes=_2

Comment: for what do you need to calc the height? Maybe there is another way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find similar solution but no one example couldn't help me. In my case I have used `UITextView` that wraps HTML text and I needed to calculate height of textView based on the content. That HTML text contained some amount of Strings  different styles and fonts. Here is one solution or probably a trick that I have implemented:

```
func calculateHeight(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, string: NSAttributedString) -> CGFloat {
    let textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textView.attributedText = string
    textView.sizeToFit()
    textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    return textView.contentSize.height
}
```

I'm not recommend you to use this code in complex layout  for example in `UICollectionViewCell` if it has a lot items for some content. It can affects on app performance. But for single check it can be relevant. Maybe it will help.